# Perforce Custom label

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, perforce

I have created a perforce custom labeller for use with CruiseControl.NET. The labeller works for most of my projects but fails to work for some. CruiseControl.NET fails on the following command:

p4 -s -c client_name -p scm:1234 -u username labelsync -l labelname

with the following error:
File(s) not in label

Tried running the above command in cmd and got the same error.

Comment: That error usually shows up when you try to use an empty label.  Can you provide a bit more context on what you're doing?

Comment: Perhaps the mappings in the client "client_name" and the label "labelname" don't match? Then possibly the client can't see any files in the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what was wrong. Perforce is Case sensitive. I changed my depot location to match with case and that solved the problem.

Comment: This is true (by default) on *nix servers.  Perforce is case insensitive with windows servers.  note too that it is possible to override the default OS setting.